# How to convert \\u0026 to & with ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, decoding

I am having a pretty basic problem where I have the following string:

```
url="http://www.autokaupat.net/Jyv%E4skyl%E4/\\u0026view=2254630"
```

The HTML encoding is not a problem, but the `\\u0026` has to be converted to `&` in order for it to work as I want it to. The following approach doesn't work for me, although it seems to be working for many others:

```
url.force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

This only works if I remove one of the leading backslashes.

Any thoughts on how that could be fixed?

Comment: A literal `\u0026` string looks like a bug. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `&` is represent as plain string `\u0026` in your `url`. That is 6 characters rather than a single character represented as unicode escape. `force_encoding` won't do your job in this case.

Try the following, to extract all unicode liked sequence in the string and replace them with the actual character at that code point.

```
url="http://www.autokaupat.net/Jyv%E4skyl%E4/\\u0026view=2254630"
url.gsub!(/\\u([a-f0-9]{4,5})/i){ [$1.hex].pack('U') }
puts url
#=> http://www.autokaupat.net/Jyv%E4skyl%E4/&view=2254630
```

Comment: This regex has a failure state. If you have a string "foo&bar" and the encoding is messed up so you have "foo\u0026bar" instead, this substitution will grab the 'b' because you are grabbing between four and five characters. If the next letter after a four character unicode code is an a-f, you will have this problem.